# Get Info Api Request

Tags: api-platform.com

currently i'm struggle with the identifier because i not need it.

i only need an get request without anything and returning some system infos.

```
/**
 * @ApiResource(
 *     itemOperations={
 *          "info"={
 *              "method"="GET",
 *              "path"="/system/info",
 *              "controller"=GetInfo::class,
 *              "read"=false
 *         }
 *     },
 *     collectionOperations={
 *
 *     }
 * )
 */
```

thats my current config but it always requires an identifier.

Comment: With respect to the id: suppose you had several systems, then you would need an id to know which system to return info from. The path could be like /info/{id} and id could be a string. If you call the one you have "system" the uri "/info/system" will return an instance of your POPO containing the system info. Be aware that caching needs to be disabled for this operation.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as if you're after not an ApiPlatform resource, but simply a standard endpoint.

Have a look at [this documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html#creating-routes-in-yaml-xml-or-php-files) from Symfony on how to define a route.

To me it sounds like you're after something like this:

`config/routes.yaml`

```yaml
system_info:
    path: /system/info
    method: GET
    controller: App\System\Info
```

With controller:

```php
namespace App\System;

class Info
{
    public function __invoke(): JsonResponse
    {
        return new JsonResponse(['pc' => 'master race']);
    }
}
```

Remember that ApiPlatform is supposed to be working with Resources (aka: DTO's and Entities), and as you're use-case does not do either, you end up struggling to make it work.

Comment: yea that will work but its not shown in the api docs.

it would be nice to have all in one place.

Comment: Actually it does mention that on the [Operations](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/operations/) documentation: `API Platform automatically registers typical CRUD operations and describes them in the exposed documentation (Hydra and Swagger). It also creates and registers routes corresponding to these operations in the Symfony routing system (if it is available).`

Comment: You do not need a custom controller, typically you would make a [POPO class](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/design/) that represents the system info. Then make it a resource, add its folder to mapping paths in api/config/packages/api_platform.yaml and finally implement a [custom ItemDataProvider](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/data-providers/#custom-item-data-provider) that instantiates it and returns the instance.